# Run a SQL query multiple times with different values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I received a SQL script below that I need to run multiple times with a different TransID value. I have 20,000 TransIDs that I need to run this on, so I believe that I need to put the 20,00 TransIDs in another table and then use the CURSOR to read that value, one at a time, and then run the whole query. Rinse and repeat. I'm not sure exactly how to work that into this script and also how to handle the output now that I may get multiple outputs per value. Can I just not drop the table and keep adding to it at the end?

Thanks for any assistance. I'm very green on this. Here's the script I've been given:

```
DECLARE @TransID uniqueidentifier SET @TransID = '**12f45e78-a234-1b3c-de34-123456789abc**' -- This is what will need to be changed 20,000 times.


DECLARE @CustomerDB nvarchar(100) 
DECLARE @FullLength int
DECLARE @TrimmedLength int
CREATE TABLE #HGtmp (
HUGIdentity nvarchar(100))

DECLARE TBLCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT HoldGroupIdentity, SavesetIdentity FROM HoldSaveset
OPEN TBLCursor 

DECLARE @HGIdentity int, @SSID int
FETCH NEXT FROM TBLCursor INTO @HGIdentity, @SSID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF @SSID = 
(SELECT SavesetIdentity FROM Saveset
WHERE idTransaction = @transID)
BEGIN

DECLARE TBLCursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT HoldGroupIdentity, HoldUserGroupID FROM HoldGroup
OPEN TBLCursor1 
DECLARE @HGIdentity1 int, @HUGIdentity nvarchar(100)

FETCH NEXT FROM TBLCursor1 INTO @HGIdentity1, @HUGIdentity
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

IF @HGIdentity = @HGIdentity1
BEGIN
SET @FullLength = (SELECT LEN(@HUGIdentity))
SET @TrimmedLength = (@FullLength - 40)
SET @CustomerDB = SUBSTRING(@HUGIdentity, 4, @TrimmedLength)
INSERT INTO #HGtmp (HUGIdentity) VALUES (@CustomerDB)
END

FETCH NEXT FROM TBLCursor1 INTO @HGIdentity1, @HUGIdentity
END
CLOSE TBLCursor1
DEALLOCATE TBLCursor1
END
FETCH NEXT FROM TBLCursor INTO @HGIdentity, @SSID
END
SELECT DISTINCT HUGIdentity AS 'DA db with Legal Holds' FROM #HGtmp

CLOSE TBLCursor
DEALLOCATE TBLCursor
DROP TABLE #HGtmp
```

Comment: You should not be using a cursor here at all. There is absolutely no need for it. All you are doing is inserting data into a temp table. This should be a single insert statement. To include the other 20,000 rows just put those into a table (or even better with a select statement) and join to that. This entire thing should be a single insert statement with no looping at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the TransIDs into a temp table with an identity column. For example, you can insert them into a temp table: #TransID

```
create table #transid (transid varchar(255), id int identity(1,1))
```

Insert your TransIDs into this table, and you'll get an integer for each one. Then just wrap your code with a WHILE statement as below:

```
declare @counter int = 1

while @counter < (select max(id)+1 from #transid)
begin 

DECLARE @TransID varchar(255) = (select transid from #transid where id = @counter)

DECLARE @CustomerDB nvarchar(100) 
DECLARE @FullLength int
DECLARE @TrimmedLength int
CREATE TABLE #HGtmp (
HUGIdentity nvarchar(100))

DECLARE TBLCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT HoldGroupIdentity, SavesetIdentity FROM HoldSaveset
OPEN TBLCursor 

DECLARE @HGIdentity int, @SSID int
FETCH NEXT FROM TBLCursor INTO @HGIdentity, @SSID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF @SSID = 
(SELECT SavesetIdentity FROM Saveset
WHERE idTransaction = @transID)
BEGIN

DECLARE TBLCursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT HoldGroupIdentity, HoldUserGroupID FROM HoldGroup
OPEN TBLCursor1 
DECLARE @HGIdentity1 int, @HUGIdentity nvarchar(100)

FETCH NEXT FROM TBLCursor1 INTO @HGIdentity1, @HUGIdentity
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

IF @HGIdentity = @HGIdentity1
BEGIN
SET @FullLength = (SELECT LEN(@HUGIdentity))
SET @TrimmedLength = (@FullLength - 40)
SET @CustomerDB = SUBSTRING(@HUGIdentity, 4, @TrimmedLength)
INSERT INTO #HGtmp (HUGIdentity) VALUES (@CustomerDB)
END

FETCH NEXT FROM TBLCursor1 INTO @HGIdentity1, @HUGIdentity
END
CLOSE TBLCursor1
DEALLOCATE TBLCursor1
END
FETCH NEXT FROM TBLCursor INTO @HGIdentity, @SSID
END
SELECT DISTINCT HUGIdentity AS 'DA db with Legal Holds' FROM #HGtmp

CLOSE TBLCursor
DEALLOCATE TBLCursor
DROP TABLE #HGtmp

set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

This should cycle through the code one time for each TransID you insert into your temp table.

Comment: Thanks for this. That helped get the first part solved but I'm now running into the second issue with the other table that's being created in this script.

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named '#HGtmp' in the database.

I'm attempting to put the HGtmp table creation outside of the script, but for some reason it's still saying that error when I execute it.

Comment: If you modified the code, can you update your OP to show exactly what you are trying to execute and the error you're getting?

Comment: Actually, I think I may have figured out a way. I'm just taking the add and drop tables out for #HGtmp so that it's not part of the script. I think I have it but give me a couple of hours to confirm. Thanks again!